# Поворот отрезка на заданный угол

Tags: c++, геометрия

Есть у меня отрезок с координатами `(x1;y1); (x2;y2)` и программа, которая вертит этот отрезок на некоторый угол вот так

```
newX1 = s1.x * cos(ang) - s1.y * sin(ang);
newY1 = s1.x * sin(ang) + s1.y * cos(ang);
newX2 = ... newY2 = ...
```

Угол изменяется от 0 с шагом в 0.01. В какой-то момент угол меня устраивает и я перестаю вертеть отрезок.

Так вот, в этот момент `ang == 0.12`. Геометрически в этот момент угол = 45 градусам (из аналитического решения.

Вопрос: откуда мне понять это без аналитического решения, что 0.12 это 45 градусов? Ибо ответ нужен в градусах.

Comment: Я убежден, что вот этот ваш алгоритм

    newX1 = s1.x * cos(ang) - s1.y * sin(ang);
    newY1 = s1.x * sin(ang) + s1.y * cos(ang);
    newX2 = ... newY2 = ...

не поворачивает отрезок, а поворачивает точки его концов вокруг начала координат.

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/sin/

    man 3 sin

> The sin() function returns the sine of x, where x is given in radians.

Отсюда можно сделать два вывода:

1) Угол для функций синуса/косинуса задается в радианах, которые переводятся в градусы по замечательной формуле `deg = rad * pi/180`.  
2) У вас где-то некислая ошибка в программе, потому что 0.12 радиан и близко не лежали к 45 градусам.

Comment: @oberlicht: тут скорее вопрос определения: вокруг _какой_ точки должен поворачиваться отрезок?

Answer (score 3):

Ваш угол `ang` - это дельта, а не абсолютное значение. А абсолютное значение, судя по постановке задачи, равно (0.01+0.02+...+0.12) = 0.78, а вот это уже вполне себе 45 градусов в радианах (точнее, 44.69 градуса). Таким образом, вам нужно либо сохранять положение отрезка, от которого выполняется поворот, и тогда вычислять угол в градусах через `deg=ang*180/PI`, либо аккумулировать `ang` каждый поворот и конвертировать в градусы аккумулированное значение.